# Can we create two provider using a single createContext?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want to use a state to transition from the first provider to the second provider and I have four pages in my React project here I am using a single createContext for two providers. Is this possible?

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const Usercontext = createContext()

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [flag, setFlag] = useState(0)
  

    return (
      <Usercontext.Provider value={{ username, setUsername, flag, setFlag}}>
        {children}
      </Usercontext.Provider>
    );
  };
  
  export default Usercontext;

  export const Adminprovider = ({child}) => {
    return (
      <Usercontext.Provider>
          {child}
      </Usercontext.Provider>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have defined two providers using the same Usercontext context.

In the Adminprovider component you should wrap it with a different context for different state management.
If you want to use a state to transition from the first provider to the second provider you should use a different context for the Adminprovider to manage its own state.

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(0);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ username, setUsername, flag, setFlag }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default UserContext;

export const AdminContext = createContext(); // Create a new context //

export const AdminProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // Manage state specific to the AdminProvider here //
  const [adminState, setAdminState] = useState("");

  return (
    <AdminContext.Provider value={{ adminState, setAdminState }}>
      {children}
    </AdminContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your valuable answer but i want to create two provider using a single createContextbut you are using 2, can you create by single createContext ?

Answer (score 1):

In the below code, I just created everything inside a context, and then I provided data by using one context to both providers. Let me know please if you find any issues in the below code.

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
const [flag, setFlag] = useState(0);

return (
<UserContext.Provider value={{ username, setUsername, flag, setFlag }}>
  {children}
</UserContext.Provider>
);
};

export const AdminProvider = ({ children }) => {
// Add state specific to the AdminProvider if needed
const [adminData, setAdminData] = useState("");

return (
<UserContext.Provider value={{ adminData }}>
  {children}
</UserContext.Provider>
);
};
//TRY THE ABOVE CODE
import React from "react";
import { UserProvider, AdminProvider } from "./your-provider-file-path";

function App() {
return (
<UserProvider>
  <AdminProvider>
    {/* Your other components */}
  </AdminProvider>
</UserProvider>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for response 
Here you wrap one provider by 2nd provider but I do not want like this 
import React from 'react'
import { Demo2 } from './Router';
import { UserProvider} from "./Context"
import Adminprovider from './Adminprovider';
import Routerfile from './Router';

function Rootprovider() {
  return (
    
    <div>
    <UserProvider>
    <div className="App">
    <Routerfile/>
    </div>
    </UserProvider>
    <Adminprovider>
    <Demo2/>
    </Adminprovider>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Rootprovider;

Can we use like this, please let me know

Comment: Yeah you are also right, you are wrapping your components individually with the <UserProvider> and <AdminProvider>. This allows each part of your application to access the specific context provided by each provider. Hope so you'll understand me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const AppContext = createContext();

export const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(0);
  const [adminState, setAdminState] = useState("");

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: { username, setUsername, flag, setFlag },
        admin: { adminState, setAdminState },
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);
```

```js
import { useAppContext } from "./AppContext";

function UserComponent() {
  const { user } = useAppContext();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        User: {user.username}
        <button onClick={() => user.setUsername("NewUsername")}>
          Change Username
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>Flag: {user.flag}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

function AdminComponent() {
  const { admin } = useAppContext();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Admin State: {admin.adminState}
        <button onClick={() => admin.setAdminState("NewAdminState")}>
          Change Admin State
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```